# CSS3 transition for "top" and "left" properties not working

Tags: css, position, css-transitions

I have a list with one item on the list transitioning to the northeast when I hover over it. Using `margin-top` and `margin-left` property transitions worked but the item being hovered over kept pushing other elements so I added `position:relative` and tried using `top` and `left` transition properties but it didn't seem to be working.

Here is the jsfiddle:

[list hover](http://jsfiddle.net/MgAYE/1/)

Comment: You're aware that this isn't going to work in older browsers, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried setting the parent of your list.  I know sometimes relative has issue unless the underlying item is also relative or absolute.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 72):

Add left, top default
[link demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MgAYE/64/)

```
left: 0px
```

Comment: Just to expand upon this answer: the browser needs to explicitly know what the start and end values are in order to calculate the transition sequence. One might reasonably assume the starting value would just be property's default value if unset, but that is not the case. The start and end values must be explicitly declared.

Comment: Like @Arctic said, this doesn't work with the `auto` keyword (the default).

Answer (score 1):

Use position:absolute and it will take it out of the normal document flow.  You could also give it z-index:5 to make sure it floats over other elements.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.transition{
    transition: all .4s;
    -moz-transition: all .4s;
    -webkit-transition:all .4s;
    -o-transition: all .4s;
    
    margin-top:20px;
    border:1px solid gray;   
    width:80px;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left:50px;
    position:relative; 
    cursor:pointer;
}

.hover_top{ 
    top:0;
}
.hover_top:hover{
    top:-10px;
}

.hover_left{    
    left:0;
}
.hover_left:hover{
    left:-10px;
}

.hover_right{   
    right:0;
}
.hover_right:hover{
    right:-10px;
}
```

```html
 

 <div class="hover_top transition"> Hover Top </div>
 <div class="hover_left transition"> Hover Left </div>
 <div class="hover_right transition"> Hover Right </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the property where you want to apply the transition effect. For example:

```
.box { position: relative; transition: all 0.4s ease;}
.box:hover { top: -1rem;}
```

that will not work. So you have to define top: 0 by default then top -1rem on hover. like

```
.box { position: relative; transition: all 0.4s ease; top:0}
.box:hover {top: -1rem}
```

that will work.